# Modifying \coadvisor command

Tags: macros, thesis

I would like to modifying the command `\coadvisor` in my thesis.

Now when I use it I get:

> **Co-orientador**: Fulano de Tal

After modification, I would like to get:

> **Coorientador**: Fulano de Tal

How do I change this "parameter" of the command in the custom [`mdtufsm.cls`](http://pastebin.com/raw/eCDZ1sKp) file?

```
%\listfiles
\documentclass[diss,twoside]{mdtufsm}
% um tipo específico de monografia pode ser informado como parâmetro opcional:
%\documentclass[tese]{mdtufsm}
% a opção `openright' pode ser usada para forçar inícios de capítulos
% em páginas ímpares
% \documentclass[openright]{mdtufsm}
% para gerar uma versão frente-e-verso, use a opção 'twoside':
% \documentclass[twoside]{mdtufsm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % pacote para conj. de caracteres correto
\usepackage{fix-cm} %para funcionar corretamente o tamanho das fontes da capa
\usepackage{times, color, xcolor}       % pacote para usar fonte Adobe Times e cores
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % pacote para acentuação
\usepackage{graphicx}  % pacote para importar figuras
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools chama amsmath
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb} %Pacotes matemáticos
\usepackage[%hidelinks%, 
            bookmarksopen=true,linktoc=none,colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue,
            pdftitle={Estudo e Desenvolvimento de uma Rede Linear de Antenas de Microfita com Feixe Chaveado e de um Receptor Homódino para Aplicação em Banda ISM},
            pdfauthor={Vinícius Ludwig Barbosa},
            pdfsubject={Dissertação de Mestrado},
            pdfkeywords={Rede de Antenas, Microfita, Receptor, Homódino, PSO}
            ]{hyperref} %hidelinks disponível no pacote hyperref a partir da versão 2011-02-05  6.82a
%Nesse caso, hidelinks retira os retângulos em volta dos links das referências

%Margens conforme MDT 7ª edição, arrumar diretamente no mdtufsm.cls para funcionar a opção twoside *PENDENTE*
\usepackage[inner=30mm,outer=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.polar}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usepgflibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=endash,position=top]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=endash,position=top]{caption}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{subcaption}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%==============================================================================
% Se o pacote hyperref foi carregado a linha abaixo corrige um bug na hora
% de montar o sumário da lista de figuras e tabelas
% Se o pacote não foi carregado, comentar a linha %
%==============================================================================
\input{macros/bugcaption}

%==============================================================================
% Identificação do trabalho
%==============================================================================
\title{Estudo e Desenvolvimento de uma Rede Linear de Antenas de Microfita com Feixe Chaveado e de um Receptor Homódino para Aplicação em Banda ISM}

\author{Ludwig Barbosa}{Vinícius}
%Descomentar se for uma "autora"
%\autoratrue

\course{Programa de Pós-Graduação em Informática}
\altcourse{Programa de Pós-Graduação em Informática}

\institute{Centro de Tecnologia}
\degree{Mestre em Ciência da Computação}

% Número do TG (verificar na secretaria do curso)
% Para mestrado deixar sem opção dentro do {}
\trabalhoNumero{}

%Orientador
\advisor[Prof.]{Dr.}{Machado}{Renato}
%Se for uma ``orientadora'' descomentar a linha baixo
%\orientadoratrue

%Co orientador, comentar se não existir
\coadvisor[Prof.]{Dr.}{Thomas Heckler}{Marcos Vinício}
%\coorientadoratrue %Se for uma ``Co-Orientadora''

%Avaliadores (Banca)
\committee[Dr.]{Uchôa-Filho}{Bartolomeu}{UFSC}
\committee[Dr.]{Rodrigues Gomes}{Natanael}{UFSM}


% a data deve ser a da defesa; se nao especificada, são gerados
% mes e ano correntes
\date{9}{Março}{2016}

%Palavras chave
\keyword{Rede de Antenas}
\keyword{PSO}
\keyword{Feixe Chaveado}
\keyword{Homódino}
\keyword{Banda ISM}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Posiciona a figura do top de uma página sem textos
\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%=============================================================================
%% Início do documento
%%=============================================================================
\begin{document}

%%=============================================================================
%% Capa e folha de rosto
%%=============================================================================
\maketitle

%%=============================================================================
%% Catalogação (obrigatório para mestrado) e Folha de aprovação
%%=============================================================================
%Somente obrigatório para dissertação, para TG, remover as linhas   77  %
%Como a CIP vai ser impressa atrás da página de rosto, as margens inner e outer 
%devem ser invertidas.
\newgeometry{inner=20mm,outer=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=20mm}    
\makeCIP{viniciuslbar@gmail.com} %email do autor        
\restoregeometry

%Se for usar a catalogação gerada pelo gerador do site da biblioteca comentar as linhas
%acima e utilizar o comando abaixo
%\includeCIP{ficha.pdf}

%folha de aprovação
\makeapprove

%%=============================================================================
%% Dedicatória (opcional)
%%=============================================================================
%\clearpage
%\begin{flushright}
%\mbox{}\vfill
%{\sffamily\itshape À UFSM ......}
%\end{flushright}

%%=============================================================================
%% Agradecimentos (opcional)
%%=============================================================================
%\chapter*{Agradecimentos}
%Obrigado ao \LaTeX por facilitar a digitação do trabalho


%%=============================================================================
%% Epígrafe (opcional)
%%=============================================================================
%\clearpage
%\begin{flushright}
%\mbox{}\vfill
%{\sffamily\itshape
%``Frase da epígrafe'' \\ }
%--- \textsc{Autor da frase}
%\end{flushright}


%%=============================================================================
%% Resumo
%%=============================================================================
\begin{abstract}
Esse trabalho de dissertação apresenta o projeto de uma rede linear de quatro antenas de microfita com patch E e o projeto de um \textit{front-end} para receptor Homódino, ambos com aplicação na banda ISM.
No contexto da antena, apresenta-se o projeto de otimização da antena patch E e o projeto de otimização e construção do protótipo da rede de quatro elementos. Essa dissertação também apresenta o algoritmo utilizado para otimizar os apontamentos desejados. Assim, esse documento também inclui a discussão sobre o método de Otimização por Enxame de Partículas (PSO), seu desenvolvimento e aplicação na síntese de quatro apontamentos em um setor de $60^{\circ}$ para a rede de antenas projetada.
No contexto do \textit{front-end}, o trabalho apresenta o projeto e caracterização de um receptor Homódino, além da construção dos protótipos de cada estágio do canal.
Tanto a rede quanto o \textit{front-end} do receptor têm seus protótipos medidos e os resultados avaliados, podendo-se constatar a bem sucedida validação destes protótipos quando comparados com resultados teóricos e simulados.
\end{abstract}

%%=============================================================================
%% Abstract
%%=============================================================================
% resumo na outra língua
% como parametros devem ser passados o titulo, o nome do curso,
% as palavras-chave na outra língua, separadas por vírgulas, o mês em inglês
%o a sigla do dia em inglês: st, nd, th ...
\begin{englishabstract}
{Analysis and Design of a Switched-Beam Linear Microstrip Antenna Array and Homodyne Receiver for ISM Band Application}
{Post-Graduate Program in Informatics}
{PSO. ISM Band. Microstrip Antenna. Antenna Array. Switched-Beamforming. Homodyne}
{March}
{th}
Considering a scenario of switched-beam system aiming to cover a $60^{\circ}$ sector provided by four distinguished radiation patterns and control of sidelobe levels, this thesis work presents the design of a four-element linear antenna array and a homodyne front-end for application in ISM Band.
For the antenna array, the project flow is detailed for the optimization of the single E-shaped microstrip anntenna which composes the linear array. 
Additionally, this document presents the algorithm method applied on the radiation pattern synthesis. The Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) is described, including algotithm flow, pameters and implementation for sets of excitation coeficients which provide the radiation patterns required.
Regarding the front-end, this document presents the design procedure to define  each receiver stage and receiver chain analysis for a homodyne receiver.
The prototype of the antenna array and front-end channel were built and data were compared to theorical and simulation results. A coherent agreement between both results validates the prototypes.
\end{englishabstract}

%% Lista de Ilustrações (opc)
%% Lista de Símbolos (opc)
%% Lista de Anexos e Apêndices (opc)

%%=============================================================================
%% Lista de figuras (comentar se não houver)
%%=============================================================================
\listoffigures

%%=============================================================================
%% Lista de tabelas (comentar se não houver)
%%=============================================================================
\listoftables

%%=============================================================================
%% Lista de Apêndices (comentar se não houver)
%%=============================================================================
%\listofappendix

%%=============================================================================
%% Lista de Anexos (comentar se não houver)
%%=============================================================================
%\listofannex

%%=============================================================================
%% Lista de abreviaturas e siglas
%%=============================================================================
 %o parametro deve ser a abreviatura mais longa
%\begin{listofabbrv}{UbiComp}
%   \item [SMD] {Surface-Mount Device}
%   \item [PML] {Perfectly Matched Layer}
%   \item [PSO] {Particle Swarm Optimization}
%\end{listofabbrv}


%%=============================================================================
%% Lista de simbolos (opcional)
%%=============================================================================
%Simbolos devem aparecer conforme a ordem em que aparecem no texto
% o parametro deve ser o símbolo mais longo
%\begin{listofsymbols}{teste}
% \item [$f_{co}$] Frequência de Corte;
%  \item [$\varnothing$] vazio;
%  \item [$\Gamma$]  Gama;
%  \item [$\forall$] Para todo;
%\end{listofsymbols}

%%=============================================================================
%% Sumário
%%=============================================================================
\tableofcontents


%%=============================================================================
%% Início da dissertação
%%=============================================================================
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip}

%Adiciona cada capitulo
%\include{capitulos/introducao}
%\include{capitulos/conceitos_microondas}
%\include{capitulos/circuitos_RF}
%\include{capitulos/antenas}
%\include{capitulos/desenvolvimento}
%\include{capitulos/resultados}
%\include{capitulos/conclusao}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

%%=============================================================================
%% Referências
%%=============================================================================
\bibliographystyle{abnt}
\bibliography{referencias/ref_dissertacao}



%IMPORTANTE: Se precisar usar alguma seção ou subseção dentro dos apêndices ou
%anexos, utilizar o comando \tocless para não adicionar no Sumário
%Exemplos: 
% \tocless\section{Histórico}
%%=============================================================================
%% Apêndices
%%=============================================================================
%\appendix
%\include{capitulos/apendicea}
%\include{capitulos/apendiceb}

%%=============================================================================
%% Anexos
%%=============================================================================
%\annex
%\include{capitulos/anexoa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Open your `.cls` file and do a search-and-replace?

Comment: First thing I tried @HerrK. . There is no explicit point with this part I would like to modify.

Comment: ...perhaps try adding `\renewcommand{\coadvisorname}{Coorientador}` to your preamble or before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed word is defined in `brazilian.babel`.

In the preamble, before `\begin{document}`, add

```
\addto\captionsbrazilian{\renewcommand\coadvisorname{Coorientador}}
```

[image]

Here's an excerpt, to show where you can put that line:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\addto\captionsbrazilian{\renewcommand{\coadvisorname}{Coorientador}}

%==============================================================================
% Se o pacote hyperref foi carregado a linha abaixo corrige um bug na hora
% de montar o sumário da lista de figuras e tabelas
% Se o pacote não foi carregado, comentar a linha %
%==============================================================================
\input{macros/bugcaption}

%==============================================================================
% Identificação do trabalho
%==============================================================================
\title{Estudo e Desenvolvimento de uma Rede Linear de Antenas de Microfita com Feixe Chaveado e de $

\author{Ludwig Barbosa}{Vinícius}
```